# How can I set the (tel:)phone handler in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, links

Gmail is smart enough to turn telephone numbers into links (most of the time) and so they make them available to click on:

[image]

They are a standard telephone link in the format of:

```
<a href="tel:323-601-1200">323-601-1200</a>
```

While browsing the web I have a handler set for the `tel:` protocol and it works fine, but inside Gmail it wants to use the builtin dialer:

[image]

How can I keep Gmail from using the dialer for `tel:` links in email messages?

Answer (score 1):

### Copy from browser

What I do is I generate the HTML to be visible in any website (a blog, one of my sites, a simple html local file written in Notepad, etc.) and then I simply copy the content selecting it directly in the browser and pasting it directly into the signature.

It's been lots of help for decades.

I just recently noted the new version of Gmail destroys those "tel:" links (even though it's a [valid current protocol](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Introduction_to_mobile_web#Cameras.2C_phones_and_other_hardware_features)). I've already sent a comment to Google from the last link in the upper-right config menu.

If many people ask for it soon, they will certainly repair that faster.